# Outlook 2013 "View Tab" not working?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have outlook 2013, When I click an email e: g Mehlo@gmail.com (To see all the emails that were sent from Mehlo@gmail.com to Mehlo@outlook.com), I click to "View Tab" then "From" and it doesn't display anything.

I have tried to check the email settings and it's working perfectly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is for arranging the displayed messages only. If you intend to search your mail, use Search box on your right, above the list of the messages